# Upgrading OS on an internet-less computer, Pro Tools compatibility

Tags: macos, high-sierra

I've a computer strictly devoted to recording that I do not connect to the internet. I just upgraded to Pro Tools 12HD (12.8.3) and my OS is Mountain Lion (10.8.2). Which installer(s) should I download to upgrade to the newest version of High Sierra?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you have another, connected Mac? Otherwise you're going to have to connect that one up; the only place to get the update is the App Store.

Comment: Tetsujin--Yes, I do!

Comment: Then download on that machine [which hopefully is also capable of running it, or it will refuse & you're back to square one] Quit the app [which will auto-launch after download], find it in Applications 'Install [os version]' & sneaker-net it to your studio machine, drop in Apps & run.

Comment: Okay, but which installer should I download? I've read about upgrading to El Capitan first, etc.

Comment: Should be able to go straight to it from ML